# Headphone Jack wire coding is different

Tags: audio, headphones, wire-terminals, color

I recently opened my headphone jack because one side of headphones wasn't working
There are 6 wires basically
Dark green, dark blue, yellow, red and two copper wires
Please help which wire should I connect to which side in the head phone jack
I am uploading the picture of headphone jack and wires enter image description here

[image]

Comment: they don't follow any rules when wireing headphone cables. you're going yo have to figrure it out by experiment.

Comment: Should I go for purchasing the DIY headphone jacks?

Comment: if you need them

Comment: Alright thanks I have purchased them hopefully they would work